# Multi-select picklist validation rule checks against position in the multi picklist instead of values

Tags: validation, validation-rule, multi-select

Hope you are all fine,

I'm doing a validation rule over a multi-select picklist that should avoid to be changed on certain substatus.  **Validation rule** is a as follows:

```
AND(
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
    ISCHANGED(substatusRoofer__c),
    OR(
        CONTAINS( PRIORVALUE ( substatusRoofer__c), "Alta de candidato roofer"),
        CONTAINS( PRIORVALUE ( substatusRoofer__c), "1")
    )        
)
```

Here i used both API Name and label, just in case, but the weird part is in **log**:

```
Profile.Name=Administrador del sistema , substatusRoofer__c=0AAB0AAC VALIDATION_PASS
```

I thought it could be hexadecimal, but is not, looks more like the order Salesforce establish over positions in the multi-select picklist, so in this case:

- 0AAA would be non selected
- 0AAB would be first value selected
- OAAB0AAC would be first and second values selected

I don't know if anyone could give me the right approach on how to do a validation rule that actually works, or understand why is Salesforce checking over the position in the picklist of the values selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The right formula is as follows:**

```
AND(
    $User.ProfileId <> 'xxxxx',
    ISCHANGED(substatusRoofer__c),
    OR(
        INCLUDES( PRIORVALUE ( substatusRoofer__c), "1"),
        INCLUDES( PRIORVALUE ( substatusRoofer__c), "12")
    )        
)
```

So the changes had been, user.profileId instead of profilename because it was checking me as "Administrador del sistema" instead of "System Administrator" and INCLUDES vs CONTAINS.

Comment: Have you tested this formula without the user profile condition?